# A completely continuous operator carries weakly Cauchy sequences into norm-convergent ones

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $X,Y$ be Banach spaces. Show that if $T:X\to Y$ is a [completely continuous operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_operator#Completely_continuous_operators), then $T$ carries weakly Cauchy sequences into norm-convergent sequences.

Let $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ be a weakly Cauchy sequence. Let us suppose that $(Tx_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is not norm-convergent, *i.e.*, it is not a Cauchy sequence. Then I don't know what can I do.

- A sequence $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is said to *converge weakly* to $x$ if for every $f\in X'$, $f(x_n)\to f(x)$.
- A sequence $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is said to be a *weak Cauchy sequence* if for every $f\in X'$ the scalar sequence $(f(x_n))_{n=1}^\infty$ is Cauchy, or, equivalently, it is convergent (because the scalar field is complete).  These notions are in general different because $(f(x_n))_{n=1}^\infty$ may converge to different points when different functionals $f$ are applied.

Comment: @Tomás Read the EDIT. I wrote the difference.

Comment: Sorry to ask @DavidMitra, but what is a weakly null sequence?

Comment: @Tomás Converges to zero weakly.

Comment: Wow @DavidMitra, with this hint the problem became so easy.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: If $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is weakly Cauchy, then for any two strictly increasing sequences of integers, $(n_k)_{k=1}^\infty$ and $(m_k)_{k=1}^\infty$, the sequence $(x_{n_k}−x_{m_k})_{k=1}^\infty$ is weakly null. This implies $(T(x_n))_{n=1}^\infty$ is norm-Cauchy.